# Use pandas groupby to find unique combinations of columns and save as df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have the following pandas Dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Colors': ['blue', 'blue', 'orange', 'red',
                              'purple', 'orange', 'purple', 'blue', 'brown'], 
                   'Price': ['500', '500', '200', '250', '300', '765', '1100', '762', 
                              '650', '625'],
                   'Style': ['farm', 'contemporary', 'modern', 'MDM', 'MDM', 
                             'contemporary', 'farm', 'contemporary', 'farm'],
                   'Location': ['far', 'near', 'far', 'far', 'near', 'far', 'far', 'near', 
                                'far']})
```

I can do `df.groupby(['Colors', 'Price', 'Style', 'Location']).size()` to get the breakdown by color to see unique combinations of Price, Style and Location wrt to Color returned as a Series.

Question - how can I use this to create a new pandas Dataframe where each column corresponds to a color (Blue, Orange, Red, etc.) and the unique combinations of values (500_contemporary_near, 500_farm_far, etc.)?

An example of the output I'm trying to generate is a dataFrame where there is a column called "Blue" and each value under (each row) is a strings such as 500_contemporary_near.

### Blue

500_contemporary_near 
500_farm_far

Answer (score 3):

You can do `unstack`

```
df.groupby(['Colors', 'Price', 'Style', 'Location']).size().unstack(level=0)
```

Comment: I tried that, but it's not exactly what I'm aiming to do. I'd like to generate a new dataFrame where for a given color, there is a column for the color (I.e. Blue) and each row underneath is a unique string of its features (500_contemporary_near). So in the end, the columns are the colors and the rows correspond to the unique string features for a given color.

Comment: @MAsoccer9 do the string join then groupby ~

Comment: Could you provide the explicit example?

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```py
pd.DataFrame([{k[0]: '_'.join(k[1:])} for k in \
   df.groupby(['Colors','Price', 'Style', 'Location']).groups]).fillna('')


    blue    brown   orange  purple  red
0   500_contemporary_near               
1   500_farm_far                
2   762_contemporary_near               
3           650_farm_far            
4                   200_modern_far      
5                   765_contemporary_far        
6                           1100_farm_far   
7                           300_MDM_near    
8                                   250_MDM_far
```

Comment: This is closer to what I'm trying to achieve. With this implementation, 500_contemporary_near, 500_farm_far and 762_contemporary_near are all under the same column "Blue" and 650_farm_far is under the column "Brown" and so forth? Is that right?

Comment: Yes, that’s correct